# Bitwise operations in Swift, reading values from beacon data

Tags: swift, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I need some help interpreting a formula. This is from the documentation of a beacon I am experimenting with. I have written it in Swift but I can't get it to work. No matter the values the temperature variable ends up as 0.

From documentation:

*The major ID broadcasts the most significant 8 bits of the humidity and the most significant 8 bits of the temperature, and the
minor ID broadcasts the next 2 bits of temperature (for a total of the 10 most significant bits) and the 14 least significant bits
of the minor ID as the really Minor configured by user.
So the humidity is 8 bits in total, and the temperature is 10 bits in total.

Example:

So the humidity:

```
uint16_t Humidity = Major(As Hex value) & 0xFF00;
```

The temperature:

```
uint16_t temperature = ((Major(As Hex value) & 0x00FF) << 8 ) & ((Minor(As Hex value) &
0xC000) >> 8);
```

The really Minor:

```
uint16_t Real Minor = Minor(As Hex value) & 0x03FF;
```

This is what I came up with and it seems correct but the result from the last bitwise AND returns 0*

```
    let majorAnd  = UInt16(beacon.major) & 0x00FF

    let majorShift = majorAnd << 8



    let minorAnd = UInt16(beacon.minor) & 0xC000

    let minorShift = minorAnd >> 8



    let temperatureResult = majorShift & minorShift
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
let temperatureResult = majorShift & minorShift
```

replace it with:

```
let temperatureResult = majorShift | minorShift
```

Bitwise AND `&` is only going to give a result when there are bits in common between the two operands.  In your case, they are mutually exclusive, You should combine them with bitwise OR `|`.

There is also a problem with the way you are shifting the values.  Here is the corrected solution:

```
let majorAnd  = UInt16(beacon.major) & 0x00FF
let majorShift = majorAnd << 2   // make space for the last 2 bits

let minorAnd = UInt16(beacon.minor) & 0xC000
let minorShift = minorAnd >> 14  // shift off the unwanted 14 bits

let temperatureResult = majorShift | minorShift
```

You'll need to shift your humidity as well:

```
let humidity = UInt16(beacon.major) & 0xFF00 >> 8
```

---

In the two shift right `>>` cases above, as a shortcut, you can skip the masking because those bits are being tossed anyway:

```
let minorShift = UInt16(beacon.minor) >> 14
let humidity = UInt16(beacon.major) >> 8
```

Comment: `|` would be more appropriate. It's just a a fluke that `+` happens to have the same result.

Comment: @Alexander, agreed that `|` is more appropriate. Edited.